# Visual Code update failing locked code.exe on windows

Tags: ide, visual-studio-code

When Visual Code asks for a update it fails and says code.exe is locked, I check with lockhunter.

I tracked the issue to the task manager, and process id 4 memory management I think is using it. I have to restart the pc to get the file deleted and I need to download visual code again. All my colleagues have the same issue.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found out it was the company software blocking the update. Seems silly. 
Please close it.